# How to determine when the scrollviewer has ended scrolling?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, windows-8, winrt-xaml, scrollviewer

I need to adjust the scrollviewer to some point after the users has completed scrolling. For that i need to get to listen to when the scrolling has ended.

iOS's UIScrollView has some similar methods

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView that is called when the scrollview

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

I tried `ViewChanging` and `ViewChanged`, But problem with handling both events simultaneously is that they occur one after another. Like following:

view changing

view changed

view changing

view changed

..

..

instead of -

view changing

view changing

view changing

view changing

view changed

Is there any way i can get the notification for when the scrollviewer has done scrolling or done scrolling-through-dragging?

Please help.

Comment: Maybe you can use the ManipulationCompleted event for this

Comment: I tried adding a handler to that also, but it never gets called. maybe because there's no change in my scrollviewer's properties.

Comment: `IsIntermediate` ? of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What You could do is :

- 1.Capture `MouseWheel` event.
- 2.Fire up a thread in the event handler of `MouseWheel`, that would count time to raise a **custom event** of yours like `FinishedScrolling`
- 3.If a `MouseWheel` event gets raised before the timer finishes, that means that the scrolling isn't done and you should terminate your timer-thread and start it again.

How's that ? It shouldn't take up too much code and if you're using MVVM you could use an Attached Behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I have searched a lot and based on that i think, right now its the only approach til MS decides to add the event.