# How to detect MouseWheel event is ended in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

When I scroll mouse wheel several MouseWheel events are fired. And I'm using these events to scale some image.

I want to call a method the moment the series of `MouseWheel` events are ended. How can I know when they end?

Here is my implementation so far

```
private void ModelWindowBorder_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{

  intervaltimer = null;

  // Do stuff like zooming and etc

  CheckEventInterval()

}

private void CheckEventInterval()
{
    intervaltimer = new Stopwatch();
    intervaltimer .Start();
    if (intervaltimer.ElapsedMilliseconds > 50)
    {
        // Do some other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no built-in event for this situation. Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234210/how-to-determine-when-the-scrollviewer-has-ended-scrolling

Comment: Yeah. The mouse wheel physically has no notion of start or stop - it is a stepper. WHen it clicks, it clicks. THis is different from all other elements that for example give a distance.

Comment: A Stopwatch is not a timer. Starting a new Stopwatch and then immediately checking its ElapsedMilliseconds property will always return a *very* small value, perhaps always zero. Your "Do some stuff" will hence never execute. Do it like shown in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, I really didn't know that about StopWatch();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually as mose wheel rotation is endless there is no special event to notify that the used ended scrolling. However in your case you can just test whether the user stopped scrolling for a short period of time. This can be done with a simple timer:

```
    //Use dispatcher timer to avoid problems when manipulating UI related objects
    DispatcherTimer timer;
    float someValue = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500 /*Adjust the interval*/);


        MouseWheel += MainWindow_MouseWheel;
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Prevent timer from looping
        (sender as DispatcherTimer).Stop();

        //Perform some action
        Console.WriteLine("Scrolling stopped (" + someValue + ")");

        //Reset for futher scrolling
        someValue = 0;
    }

    void MainWindow_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Accumulate some value
        someValue += e.Delta;

        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
    }
```

As you can see MouseWheel event will launch the timer. And if a new MouseWheel event occurs befor the timer fires it will restart the timer. In this way the timer will only fire if there is no wheel events for a specific interval.

Comment: Thanks Didier, Actually I was trying this with StopWatch() but it won't execute. Can you look at my code?

Comment: The stop watch is basicaly used to measure time. In this case your if statment is just after Start() so ellapsed time is almost 0. Actually you can't test for MouseWheel end inside MouseWheel event handler.

It is still possible to use stopwatches in this case but you need to make the test in some kind of repeated event handler like CompositionTarget.Rendering.

Comment: Thank you so much Didier, you helped me big time and your code actually works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative approach, which allows you to specify UI element (e.g. canvas, window, control etc.) for which you'd like to detect mouse wheel movements and sensitivity, which is timeout given in milliseconds, after which wheel is considered as inactive (custom stop event is fired):

```
public sealed class MouseWheelMonitor : IDisposable
{
    private AutoResetEvent _resetMonitorEvent;
    private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;
    private readonly UIElement _canvas;
    private readonly int _sensitivity;

    private bool _disposed;
    private volatile bool _inactive;
    private volatile bool _stopped;

    public event EventHandler<MouseWheelEventArgs> MouseWheel;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MouseWheelStarted;        
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MouseWheelStopped;

    public MouseWheelMonitor(UIElement canvas, int sensitivity)
    {
        _canvas = canvas;
        _canvas.MouseWheel += (s, e) => RaiseMouseWheel(e);

        _sensitivity = sensitivity;
        _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        _resetMonitorEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        _disposed = false;
        _inactive = true;
        _stopped = true;

        var monitor = new Thread(Monitor) {IsBackground = true};
        monitor.Start();
    }

    private void Monitor()
    {
        while (!_disposed)
        {
            if (_inactive) // if wheel is still inactive...
            {
                _resetMonitorEvent.WaitOne(_sensitivity/10); // ...wait negligibly small quantity of time...
                continue; // ...and check again
            }
            // otherwise, if wheel is active...
            _inactive = true; // ...purposely change the state to inactive
            _resetMonitorEvent.WaitOne(_sensitivity); // wait...
            if (_inactive) // ...and after specified time check if the state is still not re-activated inside mouse wheel event
                RaiseMouseWheelStopped();
        }
    }

    private void RaiseMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_stopped)
            RaiseMouseWheelStarted();

        _inactive = false;
        if (MouseWheel != null)
            MouseWheel(_canvas, args);
    }

    private void RaiseMouseWheelStarted()
    {
        _stopped = false;
        if (MouseWheelStarted != null)
            MouseWheelStarted(_canvas, new EventArgs());
    }

    private void RaiseMouseWheelStopped()
    {
        _stopped = true;
        if (MouseWheelStopped != null)
            _dispatcher.Invoke(() => MouseWheelStopped(_canvas, new EventArgs())); // invoked on cached dispatcher for convenience (because fired from non-UI thread)
    }    

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(!_disposed)
        {
            _disposed = true;
            DetachEventHandlers();
            if (_resetMonitorEvent != null)
            {
                _resetMonitorEvent.Close();
                _resetMonitorEvent = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void DetachEventHandlers()
    {
        if (MouseWheel != null)
        {
            foreach (var handler in MouseWheel.GetInvocationList().Cast<EventHandler<MouseWheelEventArgs>>())
            {
                MouseWheel -= handler;
            }
        }
        if (MouseWheelStarted != null)
        {
            foreach (var handler in MouseWheelStarted.GetInvocationList().Cast<EventHandler<EventArgs>>())
            {
                MouseWheelStarted -= handler;
            }
        }
        if (MouseWheelStopped != null)
        {
            foreach (var handler in MouseWheelStopped.GetInvocationList().Cast<EventHandler<EventArgs>>())
            {
                MouseWheelStopped -= handler;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage sample:

```
var monitor = new MouseWheelMonitor(uiElement, 1000);
monitor.MouseWheel += (s, e) => { Debug.WriteLine("mouse wheel turned"); };
monitor.MouseWheelStarted += (s, e) => { Debug.WriteLine("mouse wheel started"); };
monitor.MouseWheelStopped += (s, e) => { Debug.WriteLine("mouse wheel stopped"); };
```